# How do I clear a table from SQL Server's cache?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a few tables in my database that should not be cached.

How do I tell SQL Server not to cache a table's pages or how do I flush a single table from the cache?

Flushing all the cache is not an option.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: On what basis have you decided that the tables should not be cached?

Comment: If your tables are being cached then they're being queried. If they are accessed infrequently then the SQL Server Memory manager will flush them out in preference of other objects at the required time. What's your goal here?

Comment: @John - No idea what the OP's goal is but there are times where this would be useful. e.g. doing a one off scan against a large table without flushing the buffer pool.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Hmmm I can see why that could be useful. The SQL Server DB Engine cannot bypass the Buffer Pool though. All data pages must be read from disk and then into memory in order to be accessed.

Comment: @JohnSansom - Agreed but there is an internal mechanism to immediately disfavor specific pages that could potentially be used. Just not exposed in any way to us AFAIK.

Comment: Some of the reasons: low-priority table, iis/rs on the same machine as sql server, power usage, etc.  The most important is that some tables are low priority tables with regard to the application's performance and can be safely read from disk whenever they are accessed. By keeping those tables out of the buffer pool, memory analysis becomes somewhat easier.

Comment: @user973156: Is your code and design *that good* that you can now only 2nd guess SQL Server to make things better?

Comment: I have a similar question. We want to prevent caching on a table with large image blobs, while allowing caching for some (less frequently accessed) tables, similar to QOS optimization on networks. I guess the only option right now is to use a different instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way of doing this.

`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` doesn't accept any parameters for a specific database or object. Internally SQL Server can do this at a database level however as when a database is `AUTO_CLOSE`d all corresponding pages are removed from the buffer cache.

Also internally SQL Server can mark certain pages such that they will be the first ones kicked out by the lazy writer. This is used by DMVs such as `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` to avoid flushing the buffer pool as alluded to in [this article](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-sysdm_db_index_physical_stats.aspx) but this functionality is not exposed in any way to us (even though it might be useful to be able to specify the same if doing a one off scan of a large table for example).

Answer (score 7):

You can not specify that specific tables should not be cached.  What makes you think that you don't want the tables in cache?

SQL Server does ALL its normal operations in the buffer pool so if you were able to tell SQL Server not to load a table into cache that table wouldn't be accessible for any normal DML operations.